# Build/compile errors because of compilerOptions in legacy_code

Tags: matlab, mex, legacy-code, compiler-options

I want to create some trivial S-function with `legacy_code` for my `MexTest.c`:

```
legacy_code('compile', specs, compilerOptions)
```

There are 2 macros (`TEST_DEF1` and `TEST_DEF2`), which I want to put into `compilerOptions`. The 2 macros are used in the function `TestFnc()`.
But somehow, the `TestFnc()` does not see the 2 macros defined in `compilerOptions` before...

**MexTest.c:**

```c
#include "MexTest.h"
void TestFnc(double *p_u, double *p_y)
{
 
    *p_y = *p_u + 1;
    
    #ifndef TEST_DEF1
        #error "undefined: TEST_DEF1"
    #endif
    
    #ifndef TEST_DEF2
        #error "undefined: TEST_DEF2"
    #endif
}
```

**MexTest.h:**

```c
#ifndef MEXTEST_H_
#define MEXTEST_H_

void TestFnc(double *p_u, double *p_y);

#endif
```

**legacy_code tool**

```matlab
specs               = legacy_code('initialize');
specs.HeaderFiles   = {'MexTest.h'};
specs.SourceFiles   = {'MexTest.c'};
specs.SFunctionName = 'Test_SFunc_gen';
specs.OutputFcnSpec = 'void TestFnc(double u1[1], double y1[1])';
%% Compile C-MEX-s-function
legacy_code('sfcn_cmex_generate', specs);
legacy_code('generate_for_sim',specs);
legacy_code('compile', specs, {'-DTEST_DEF1', '-DTEST_DEF2'});
```

**Mex Build Errors:**

```
### Start Compiling Test_SFunc_gen
    mex('-IC:\Users\xxxx\Documents\', '-c', '-outdir', 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tp05e00c12_2732_4dab_a0f8_f30bd05992f8', 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MexTest.c')
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
Error using mex
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MexTest.c: In function 'TestFnc':
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MexTest.c:8:10: error: #error "undefined: TEST_DEF1"
         #error "undefined: TEST_DEF1"
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MexTest.c:12:10: error: #error "undefined: TEST_DEF2"
         #error "undefined: TEST_DEF2"
```

How could I use the `-D` option correctly for my case?

(Matlab version 2021a)

Comment: I don't see the '-DTEST_DEF1' and '-DTEST_DEF2' options being used on the mex command line.

Comment: Hi @JamesTursa Thank you for your reply! :) How could I put the  '-DTEST_DEF1' and '-DTEST_DEF2' options into the `legacy_code('compile', specs)` ? Best regards Tony

Comment: I don't use the legacy_code tool so it is hard to advise you. My observation is that, even though I see those compile options listed in your legacy_code tool compile call, I don't see those options repeated on the actual mex call line.  The only thing I might suggest is using a single string instead of a cell array of strings. E.g., legacy_code('compile', specs, '-DTEST_DEF1 -DTEST_DEF2');

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it does not work.. :(